# New 2023 TeXlive, similar but different arara problem

Tags: texlive, texstudio, texworks, arara, terminal-output

I had previously posted a question about Arara, with TeXlive 2022 and with specific reference to ConTeXt (see [ConTeXt and Arara, failure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679661/texworks-run-context-compiler-from-arara?noredirect=1#comment1691318_679661). That question has been closed due to "lack of clarity", and I have abandoned it in lieu of this new question.

So:
I now have TeXlive 2023 installed from ISO -> USB method (see [2023 TeXlive install failure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1694457?noredirect=1).
When I attempt to run Arara within TeXstudio, TeXworks, or Kile, arara simply gives me the 'splash' display, as so:

```
Usage: arara [OPTIONS] file...

    __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _
   / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
  | (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
   \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

  The cool TeX automation tool.

  arara executes the TeX workflow you tell it to execute. Simply specify your
  needs within your TeX file and let arara do the work. These directives
  feature conditional execution and parameter expansion.

Options:
  -l, --log                        Generate a log output
  -v, --verbose / -s, --silent     Print the command output
  -n, --dry-run                    Go through all the motions of running a
                                   command, but with no actual calls
  -S, --safe-run                   Run in safe mode and disable potentially
                                   harmful features. Make sure your projects
                                   uses only allowed features.
  -w, --whole-file                 Extract directives in the file, not only in
                                   the header
  -p, --preamble TEXT              Set the file preamble based on the
                                   configuration file
  -t, --timeout INT                Set the execution timeout (in milliseconds)
  -L, --language TEXT              Set the application language
  -m, --max-loops INT              Set the maximum number of loops (> 0)
  -d, --working-directory PATH     Set the working directory for all tools
  -P, --call-property VALUE        Pass parameters to the application to be
                                   used within the session.
  --generate-completion [bash|zsh|fish]
                                   Generate a completion script for arara. Add
                                   'source <(arara --generate-completion
                                   <shell>)' to your shell's init file.
  -V, --version                    Show the version and exit
  -h, --help                       Show this message and exit

Arguments:
  file  The file(s) to evaluate and process
```

**NOTE:** I view this is an improvement of sorts when compared to the prior error that I had, wherein arara told me that it `**could not access the arara.jar file**`

**NOTE:** I can successfully run arara from the terminal window, but ONLY if the terminal window is opened from the folder where the 'my_document.tex' file resides:

```
username@username-computername:~/Documents/documents_2022_2023/specific_documents$ arara my_document.tex
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Processing "my_document.tex" (size: 7.1 kB, last modified:
2023-04-15 19:52:08), please wait.

(LuaLaTeX) LuaLaTeX engine .............................. SUCCESS

Total: 1.513 seconds
username@username-computername:~/Documents/documents_2022_2023/specific_documents$
```

IF, on the other hand, I execute the same command from the same directory, ***under Root control:***

```
username@username-computername:~/Documents/documents_2022_2023/specific_documents# arara my_document.tex
```

the operation fails. It issues a reply,

```
root@username-computername:/home/username/Documents/documents_2022_2023/specific_documents# arara my_document.tex
Error: Unable to access jarfile
root@username-computername:/home/username/Documents/documents_2022_2023/specific_documents
```

It seems to me that the behavior in terminal mode must offer some clue(s) as to why I cannot get arara to run in any of the TeX-specific editors. Clearly, it has something to do with permissions. But, I cannot see and understand where it comes off the rails, so to speak.

Comment: “IF, on the other hand, I execute the same command from the same directory, under Root control”: I would assume that in root you do not have set up all necessary paths for TeX Live which seemingly do work in your user. However, you should never run something like arara (which can execute arbitrary system commands) as root.

Comment: “When I attempt to run Arara within TeXstudio, TeXworks, or Kile, arara simply gives me the 'splash' display, as so” Do you have any means of getting the command-line that these editors try to run (and the exit code they get)? `arara` will only output said splash screen if it is run without arguments or with the help flag. Neither of which any editor should run. Are you sure that the editors actually pass on the file argument?

Comment: In TeXstudio, I have set up a user-command which is ``arara | "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/arara.sh" | "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/arara.jar" ``

Comment: in Kile, the arara command is ``/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/arara``

Comment: I used the arara "generate completion" option, generated a bash completion file, and put it in the bash-completion folder as, ``usr/share/bash-completion/completions/arara``. This doesn't seem to be the answer, unless the system needs to be re-booted or "sourced"

Comment: I solved the 'Arara' problem in TeXstudio, TeXworks, and Kile. I will provide a formal answer, with details, soon.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Your commands look a bit spotty to me as they call arara without parameters and in TeXStudio seemingly thrice. Note that the bash-completions are not what you think they are, they only allow your shell (bash) to show completion suggestions for the parameter (when you hit TAB, for instance, like when you want to auto-complete file names). Shell completions are definitely unrelated to anything in terms of compile behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments, TeXnician! See my self-answer. I hope this is helpful to others

Answer (score 1):

After carefully examining the compiling commands (pdflatex, lualatex...etc) within each of the editors (TeXworks, TeXstudio, Kile), I have solved my own problem. A clue came from the fact that, although *Arara* would run from the terminal, when it was called from within these TeX editors, it would display the same "splash" screen as found at the terminal were you to run the command `$ arara`, ***without** specifying a target file to process*.

I still have NO idea of how **all three** of these editors came to simultaneously have the same issue with running *Arara* (they were running fine previously). It will probably remain a mystery.

As I hinted above, in every case the problem arose from within the editor because *Arara* was **not** supplied with a ***.tex** file-name to work on (NB: my intuition that the compiler would automatically [magically?] use the file that was "in progress", was *wrong*.)

The editor must be set-up to supply the ***.tex** file-name when *Arara* is called.  Here are the setup requirements for each editor that I've been experimenting with:

**For TeXstudio:**
Go to OPTIONS --> Configure TeXstudio --> Build --> User Commands; choose "+Add" , then add this Path to the *arara* program (placed inside double quotes, as shown below), to which it is appended **%.tex**:
`"/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/arara" %.tex`
Click OK to exit.
Check your editors function with a known-good *.tex file that compiles with a known compiler (say, pdflatex); for example, add
`% arara: pdflatex`
as the first line of your preamble.
**NOTE:** with ConTeXt, you will have to use the suffix **.tex** for your working file, even though the ConTeXt team doesn't recommend using the normal *.tex extension (to distinguish them, my ConTeXt documents now appear as `my_filename.mkiv.tex`) ****.

**For TeXworks:**
from the menu, choose Edit --> Preferences -->Typesetting;
Choose (or create anew) the Processing Tool from the list; then click Edit...; then in the Tool Configuration Menu enter
Name: *arara*
Program: *arara*
Arguments: $fullname
(you may choose to "view PDF after running")
Click OK.
Test your system with a known good *.tex file, using *arara* as the compiler, as suggested above

**For Kile:**
From the menu, Settings --> Configure Kile --> Build
Select the tool *arara* (or add it, if necessary); then you will have to configure the tool using the 3-tabbed menu on the right;
Select: Default  {<---See my note at ***, below}
Under the "General" tab, choose
Command: *arara*
Options: %source
Under the "Advanced" tab,
Type: Run Outside of Kile
Class: Compile
Source Extension: (leave blank)
Target Extension: PDF
Target File: (leave blank)
relative dir: (leave blank)
(click OK)
Test your Kile editor with *arara*, as outlined above

**To recap:** the *.tex file to be compiled is tagged in three different ways:
In TeXstudio, it is "***.tex**";
In TeXworks, it is "**$fullname**"; and,
In Kile, it is "**%source**"

*** A 2nd configuration might be added, specifically for ConTeXt using a specific engine (ConTeXt-Lualatex, for example), but I have not tested this

****It is likely that a 2nd User Command (named "arara-Context", for example) can be added, with a different file extension as the target (for example, **%.mkiv**), but I have not tested this yet

Comment: To me it more seems like you haven't setup the PATH correctly. How did you do that? If the PATH is set correctly you don't need full paths to programmes in the settings of the editors.

Comment: Further comment: arara does not need the .tex extension. If you have a file `mytex.tex` it will run just fine being called as `arara mytex`. Changing `%.tex` to `%` will therefore still work and solve your ConTeXt problem in TeXStudio.

Comment: What changes would be needed to set-up the PATH correctly?

Comment: In TeXstudio, I just changed ``%.tex`` to (first) ``%``, then to ``%. ``, then to ``%.mkiv`` --- In all three cases, I got the same error message from Arara:

Comment: that error msg being ``"I could not find the provided file "new_context." [ .tex | .dtx |
.ltx | .drv | .ins ]. Please make sure the file exists and it has
a valid extension."``

Comment: Well, you need the file name without the `.`. Only `new_context`. The documentation says `%` is the filename of the root file without extension, so with just `%` (not `%.`, that won't work!) you should get the correct execution. But please make sure to make `mkiv` known to arara (it's not one of the default extensions, so you have to add mkiv to your local arara config). I just mentioned the `%` way as a way for you to avoid the `.mkiv.tex` situation which you mentioned as if it was necessary (it isn't if you configure your tools appropriately).

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I am looking for the arara configuration file but, even with the Arara manual's help, I cannot find anything other than ``defaultSettings.yaml``. It seems to me, based on my reading of the arara manual, that the user must create (from scratch) such a configuration file. I'm finding the arara manual seems to presume a thorough knowledge of "yaml" and the vagaries of the arara installation.

Comment: @Birdman If you have ideas how to improve the manual, feel free to open an issue. However, [the arara manual has an introduction into YAML](https://islandoftex.gitlab.io/arara/manual/yaml/). And each and every software manual I read up to now assumes that you at least read the manual. In my case, I referred to the configuration file which has an entire chapter titled `Configuration file` where you want to have a look at the `filetypes` property. If you need help creating an arara configuration, feel free to ask questions at the appropriate places.

Comment: I had read the Arara manual, but _not_ cover-to-cover. Thanks for pointing out that there is a section on YAML in the manual. It occurs in the last dozen pages --  on pg 175 of 187. The earliest reference to p 175 occurs on page 9: _"a rule is a plain text file written in the YAML format, described in Chapter 10, on page 175."_ I **did** read this paragraph, but the syntax of that sentence indicates that it is **rules** which are described on page 175 (not the YAML format / markup language as such). In any case, that appended section still requires a thorough knowledge of coding...

Comment: ...that "_[YAML] is a human-friendly, cross-language, Unicode-based data-serialization language designed around the common, native-data-type of programming languages"_ is beyond my comprehension at this time [NB: punctuation added]. To get to the crux: on page 40 it says that Arara "looks for at least one of four files" of the format, *.yaml before execution. I cannot find **any** of those four files. Yet, Arara is still functioning. So I conclude that 1) either it is still hiding somewhere (!); or 2) perhaps that a configuration file is not strictly **necessary** for the execution of Arara.

Comment: As I said before, if you have complaints about the manual being unclear, open an issue in the arara repo. Concerning the configuration files: of course, they are optional, there's a concept of “default values” and by default arara tries to do what most users expect. However, that does not include custom file extensions etc, so if you need them you have to create a configuration file and overwrite some of the defaults.

Comment: Btw: If you want to interact with a person here, make sure to tag them. I stumbled across your comments by chance, I won't receive a notification from StackExchange if you do not tag me (`@TeXnician`).

Comment: @TeXnician - thanks for your reply. I was unaware of the use of the tags to force a notification to a particular user (as the originator, I am guessing that I always receive Email updates to changes here).

Comment: @TeXnician - I would appreciate some help with creating a configuration help, if you are willing to provide that help. I am always willing to provide editorial comments, re-writes and suggestions to improve documentation (I am a professional technical writer). I will attempt to open an issue at the arara repository site.

Comment: I'm watching the arara tag on this site, so if you do ask a question here about specifics of configuration files, I can surely try to answer. Or we get arara's creator @PauloCereda to help. So if there are certain things that are unclear to you, you can maybe ask for the technical support here and then use what you learned to improve arara's documentation? That way you could kill two birds with one stone (get your setup working and improve the documentation). Otherwise, I'm not sure how I could “help with creating a configuration help”.

Comment: @TeXnician - By re-writing Ch. 4, I figured out enough to be dangerous, and so start hacking. I appended my config file to the original question. That config no longer creates error messages. Arara now seems to recognize the *.mkiv extension as valid....BUT, Arara is throwing an error that it cannot find any `directives` in the file (but they exist, and they work if I change the file extension to *.mkiv.tex). Also, I created a default preamble in the config file, and that does NOT help --- I still get the error 'no directive found...' What I am I missing here ? The logs are not helpful.

Comment: @Birdman Sorry, I don't see your config file in the original question. Editing is not intended for new questions anyway. If you need help with your config file it's best if you open a new question. Right now, I can only guess what you have done and from the error it sounds as if you did not set the `pattern` for the file type correctly (see the manual on the default pattern, it should work for ConTeXt files).

Comment: @TeXnician - please see new question, [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685440/arara-configuration-file-create-new-file-extension-file-type-context)