# Arara configuration file, create new file extension (file type); ConteXt

Tags: context, arara

This question follows-on from a previous one [...similar but different Arara...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683024/new-2023-texlive-similar-but-different-arara-problem/683853?noredirect=1#comment1700235_683853)
I've created a configuration file according to what I understand from the Arara Reference Manual, and I have appended it below.

The configuration file itself does not (after some tweaking...!) flag any error messages about itself during run-time. Arara appears to recognize and accept my newly created file-extension `*.mkiv` .

However, at runtime, Arara tells me `It looks like no directives were found in the provided file. Make sure to include at least one directive and try again.`
That is not true, the file does have a directive.  As a test, I added a default preamble to my configuration file `defaultPreamble: onecontext`. This did not help, and has since been removed from the configuration file (as it interferes with non-ConTeXt executions)

In fact, Arara runs without error on this file (which has an arara directive) if I don't have the configuration file in place, or if I append the file name with `*.tex`, such as `myfilename.mkiv.tex`

The arara logs don't provide any useful information.

So, what am I missing here?

```
 1 !config
 2 filetypes:
 3   - extension:  ins 
 4   - extension:  drv
 5   - extension:  ltx
 6   - extension:  dtx
 7   - extension:  tex
 8   - extension:  mkiv
 9      pattern: ^\s*//\s*
10 paths:
11     - '/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/rules'
12 loops: 5
13 verbose: true
14 logging: true
15 header: true
16 logname: my_arara_log
17 preambles:
18     onecontext: |
19         % arara: context
20 defaultPreamble: onecontext      [<-- added for testing, then deleted]
```

Answer (score 4):

We cannot know what you are missing if you only provide half of the truth. In this case, you did not provide your ConText file. When I read your config file and file patterns, I assume your average ConTeXt file looks like

```
// arara: context
\starttext
Hello world
\stoptext
```

Well, assuming that you have not reinvented ConTeXt and its syntax, this is a syntax error. But please note that with `^\s*//\s*` you will not get anywhere with valid ConTeXt syntax.

Obviously, you have copied and pasted the pattern from the documentation without understanding the regular expression. And you did not look up two lines to try the default pattern which works in basically all TeX files (and is used by default): `^\s*%\s*`.

Hence, assuming you want to feed a valid ConTeXt document like

```
% arara: context
\starttext
Hello world
\stoptext
```

into arara, you can use a configuration file with an appropriate pattern. If you use your original pattern, it is quite self-explanatory that arara would not find directives in the document because there is no `// arara` line anywhere in that file.

```yaml
!config
filetypes:
  - extension:  ins 
  - extension:  drv
  - extension:  ltx
  - extension:  dtx
  - extension:  tex
  - extension:  mkiv
    pattern: ^\s*%\s*
```

Comment: You are correct: I am in a muddle about ``patterns``. When you say "you did not look up two lines...", do you mean the first indented paragraph on page 47 (which is two sentences and 6 lines)?  Page 47 indicates that the pattern ^\s*%\s* is for the 5 default file types. The explanation goes on to talk about "new file types", and then gives ^\s*//\s* as the example of a pattern, which I presumed was to be used for every user-defined file type (....more to follow...)

Comment: ... which is, of course, what I used in my config file. Now, you are also correct: If I change the preamble in my ConTeXt file to ``// arara: context``, it successfully compiles.  So now, if I understand correctly, the ``pattern key`` such as the default ^\s*%\s*, defines how ``arara`` will recognize those lines in the TeX-file's preamble that are ``arara directives'' .    The leading character in the directive's line is whatever character(s) that are placed in the position of the underscore, here:   `` ^\s*_\s* ``  (..more...)

Comment: If I wanted my TeX -file directive to look like this ``$$ arara: context`` my YAML  ``pattern key`` would be `` ^\s*$$\s* ``

Comment: @Birdman No, I mean two lines, technically one (I counted a blank line) because I have started counting from the bullet's start but this discussion about counting is pointless, you obviously understood where I was pointing to. And your presumption about the pattern is wrong because it is as much an example as the `extension: c` for the extension key (you can define other custom extensions than just c). Pattern does what it says it does in the documentation (there is no clear single sentence to quote but the paragraph describes that the pattern is used to identify lines containing directives).

Comment: Your understanding of the pattern key about leading character etc. pp. is not wrong but far too restrictive. You are not required to have things at line start (`^`), you do not have to allow whitespace `\s*`, you do not need to allow whitespace afterwards. `AbC` would be a perfectly valid (even though practically useless) pattern matching all lines in the document which contain `AbC` anywhere in the line.  Therefore, I cannot describe it more succinctly than by `provide a pattern to match` like you would in the regex search function of your editor or in other software with regex support.

Comment: In fact, I did not 'obviously understand', otherwise I would not have elaborated about it. I just wanted to 'get on the same page' with you, not to annoy you! ... Perhaps it is surprising that I have got this far without recognizing and understanding 1) what regex IS, 2) that the characters in the ``pattern`` are to be understood as regex

Comment: @Birdman Sorry, I agree the “obvious” was judgemental. Anyway, concerning (2) the first sentence about `patterns` states `This key holds the directive lookup pattern as a regular expression`, so the manual is clear about that patterns is to be interpreted as regular expression (it even repeats it for custom file types: `Make sure to provide a valid regular expression as key value.`). Concerning (1) later in the chapter it is suggested you consult background documentation on regular expressions because the manual does not cover it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145957/discussion-between-birdman-and-texnician).